# Getting undefined When trying to access items in a JSON response from Spotify

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, spotify

I am fetching data from a spotify playlist:

```
fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DXbvABJXBIyiY?fields=tracks.items(track(name,href,album(name,href)))"
```

this is the response I'm getting:

[spotify response to console.log(props.responseSong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbeo9.png)

[spotify response to console.log(props.responseSong.tracks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soScW.png)

When trying to drill down to items (which I eventually want to map through)

```
console.log(props.responseSong.tracks.items)
```

I get 'cannot read items of undefined'.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, how can I access this array of items?

Any help or advice would be very helpful, thank you!

Here is the the component making the request:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import queryString from 'query-string'
import ShowRainySong from '../Songs/ShowRainySong'

const RainySong = () => {
    
    let [responseSong, setResponseSong] = useState({})
    let parsed = queryString.parse(window.location.search)
    let accessToken = parsed.access_token
    console.log('token',accessToken)

    function getRainySong(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DXbvABJXBIyiY?fields=tracks.items(track(name,href,album(name,href)))", {
                "headers": { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    setResponseSong(response)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err)
                })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log('song', responseSong)}
            <button onClick={getRainySong}>Get Song</button>
            <ShowRainySong responseSong={responseSong}
            />
        </div>
           
    )
}

export default RainySong
```

and the component that would show the response:

```
import React from 'react'

const ShowRainySong = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log('return show song', props.responseSong.tracks.items)}
            <div>
                {/* {props.responseSong.items.map(song => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <p>{song.track.artists[0].name}</p>
                        </div>
                    )})} */}
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default ShowRainySong
```

Comment: We need to see the entire code when you get, store and display the data please.

Comment: The error `cannot read items of undefined` means that `props.responseSong.tracks` is `undefined`. I'd look at the response from the api and figure out if if any errors are being thrown from the api

Comment: can you upload the spotify response?

Comment: Whats the output for console.log(props.responseSong) from within the ShowRainySong component?

Comment: Thank you. I am not seeing any errors in my response. The thing is that I can access `props.responseSong.tracks` and get the correct response without any errors, until I try to drill down to items, then it's undefined.

Comment: Could you show us what's inside setResponseSong(response) please?

Comment: Additionally, if you change our console.log to "console.log(props.responseSong.tracks)" or "console.log(props.responseSong)", what are the respective outputs?

Comment: I've linked an image in my original question of my console showing the response to `props.responseSong` from spotify. It's titled 'spotify response'.

Comment: I know, I'm specifically interested in what the console outputs though. It might not be different, but I believe it would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Getting the same response (as the one in my image) in `setResponseSong(response)`

Comment: For both logging props.responseSong.tracks AND for props.responseSong you get the same?

Comment: Try console.log(props.responseSong.tracks?.items) and see if that fixes your error. I've had similar errors in the past where optional chaining helped, but without being able to play around in the code I don't know myself if that'll do it.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @EdwardBlack Thank you so much! That worked!! Thank you thank you!